# Model fitting with nls.lm in R, "Error: unused argument"

Tags: r, nls, model-fitting

I'm trying to use the nls.lm function in the minpack.lm to fit a non-linear model to some data from a psychophysics experiment.

I've had a search around and can't find a lot of information about the package so have essentially copied the format of the example given on the nls.lm help page. Unfortunately my script is still failing to run and R is throwing out this error:

```
Error in fn(par, ...) : 
unused argument (observed = c(0.1429, 0.2857, 0.375, 0.3846, 0.4667, 0.6154))
```

It appears that the script thinks the data I want to fit the model to is irrelevant, which is definitely wrong.

I'm expecting it to fit the model and produce a value of 0.5403 for the spare parameter (w).

Any help is greatly appreciated.
I'm making the transfer from Matlab over to R so apologies if my code looks sloppy.

Here's the script.

```
  install.packages("pracma")
  require(pracma)
  install.packages("minpack.lm")
  require(minpack.lm)

  # Residual function, uses parameter w (e.g. .23) to predict accuracy error at a given ratio [e.g. 2:1]
  residFun=function(w,n) .5 * erfc( abs(n[,1]-n[,2])/ ((sqrt(2)*w) * sqrt( (n[,1]^2) + (n[,2]^2) ) ) )

  # example for residFun
  # calculates an error rate of 2.59%
  a=matrix(c(2,1),1,byrow=TRUE)
  residFun(.23,a)

  # Initial guess for parameter to be fitted (w)
  parStart=list(w=0.2)

  # Recorded accuracies in matrix, 1- gives errors to input into residFun
  # i.e. the y-values I want to fit the model
  Acc=1-(matrix(c(0.8571,0.7143,0.6250,0.6154,0.5333,0.3846),ncol=6))

  # Ratios (converted to proportions) used in testing
  # i.e. the points along the x-axis to fit the above data to
  Ratios=matrix(c(0.3,0.7,0.4,0.6,0.42,0.58,0.45,0.55,0.47,0.53,0.49,0.51),nrow=6,byrow=TRUE)

  # non-linear model fitting, attempting to calculate the value of w using the Levenberg-Marquardt nonlinear least-squares algorithm 
  output=nls.lm(par=parStart,fn=residFun,observed=Acc,n=Ratios)

  # Error message shown after running
  # Error in fn(par, ...) : 
  #   unused argument (observed = c(0.1429, 0.2857, 0.375, 0.3846, 0.4667, 0.6154))
```

Answer (score 2):

The error means you passed a function an argument that it did not expect. `?nls.lm` has no argument `observed`, so it is passed to the function passed to `fn`, in your case, `residFun`. However, `residFun` doesn't expect this argument either, hence the error. You need to redefine this function like this :

```
# Residual function, uses parameter w (e.g. .23) to predict accuracy error at a given ratio [e.g. 2:1]
residFun=function(par,observed, n) {
  w <- par$w
  r <- observed - (.5 * erfc( abs(n[,1]-n[,2])/ ((sqrt(2)*w) * sqrt( (n[,1]^2) + (n[,2]^2) ) ) ))
  return(r)
}
```

It gives the following result :

```
> output = nls.lm(par=parStart,fn=residFun,observed=Acc,n=Ratios)
> output
Nonlinear regression via the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm
parameter estimates: 0.540285874836135 
residual sum-of-squares: 0.02166
reason terminated: Relative error in the sum of squares is at most `ftol'.
```

Why that happened :

It seems that you were inspired by this example in he [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/minpack.lm/minpack.lm.pdf) :

```
## residual function
residFun <- function(p, observed, xx) observed - getPred(p,xx)
## starting values for parameters
parStart <- list(a=3,b=-.001, c=1)
## perform fit
nls.out <- nls.lm(par=parStart, fn = residFun, observed = simDNoisy,
xx = x, control = nls.lm.control(nprint=1))
```

Note that `observed` is an argument of `residFun` here.

Comment: Ah! Thank you!
I knew it would be something obvious.

So this should work (at least until the next error)?

`residFun=function(w,observed, n) observed= .5 * erfc( abs(n[,1]-n[,2])/ ((sqrt(2)*w) * sqrt( (n[,1]^2) + (n[,2]^2) ) ) )`

Comment: no, it won't work because `observed` is not a parameter of your function, but its output. I updated my answer with a function that works